# Reference request: Hard measure theory / functional analysis problems

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, reference-request

I want to revise basic measure theory and functional analysis and I was wondering if there's a good source of challenging problems? Ideally I'm hoping these problems will help me go through the material again, as I know that this is the best way to learn. Preferably, there are worked out solutions to refer to as well, but at the very least hints? One possibility is to say "just look at the problems at the end of the chapters in Rudin" but I'm wondering if there are any other good sources you know of.

Comment: You could check qualifying exams from PhD programs. They tend to ask challenging questions and, if you’re lucky, you may find an answer key.

Comment: @RocketMan Thanks for the suggestion. I can do that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You might try Biler and Witkowski, [Problems in Mathematical Analysis](https://books.google.ca/books?id=ILs6DwAAQBAJ)

Comment: Looks like a good book! People on this website give interesting recommendations as always! Thank you.